# How can I make script work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby.
I need to make this script work:

```
puts "Do you like cats?"
ask = gets

def ask(n)

 if ask == yes
   return "I do too"
 end

 if ask == no
   return "Dogs are better"
 end
end

puts "#{ask(n)}"
```

Error message is :

> pracif.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method`n' for
>   main: Object (NameError)

Comment: quote 'no' and 'yes' and its n == "yes" n == "no" not ask ==

Comment: Please read "[ask]", including the pages linked at the bottom, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that would work for you :

```
puts "Do you like cats?"
answer = gets

def ask(n)

 if n == 'yes'
   return "I do too"
 end

 if n == 'no'
   return "Dogs are better"
 end
end

puts ask(answer.downcase.chomp)
```

**Explaination**

1. As the error said you were trying to pass in a variable `n` which was not defined
2. Secondly you have a method name `ask` same as variable name. I've renamed the variable to `answer` instead
3. Thirdly, enclose `yes` and `no` in quotes
4. And finally, since you are using `gets` a `\n` gets appended like `yes\n` so none of your conditions would match. So i've used `chomp` to remove `\n`. And also used `downcase` to make input case insensitive.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Jordan in the comments, there is no reason to use string interpolation for the puts statement. So it's enough to call the method directly.

Comment: Yeah, now it works! Thanks a lot. I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: There is never a reason to do `puts "#{foo}"`. `#{...}` is for string interpolation—i.e. interpolating values into a string that has other content, like `"Hello, #{name}"`—but in `"#{ask(...)}"` there's no other content so you're just doing the equivalent of `puts ask(...).to_s`. In this case, though, `ask` always returns a string, so there's no need for `to_s`. Furthermore, `puts` automatically calls `to_s` on its arguments, so `to_s` is unnecessary here, too. Just do `puts ask(...)`.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks, i had missed that. I've updated the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has no `n` local variable defined that you are passing to your `ask(n)` method at the end.

Rename your `ask` variable that your script `gets` from user to `answer` for example and pass it to your `ask` method at the end like so:

*Updated code to fix other problem I did not see in the first run.*

```
puts "Do you like cats?"
answer = gets.chomp

def ask(n)
  (n == 'yes') ? "I do too" : "Dogs are better"
end

puts "#{ask(answer)}"
```

Comment: This won't work. There are a lot of issues with this response.

Comment: might want to enclose the values `yes` and `no` in quotes

Comment: Indeed, it won't work! I saw the first problem with the variable name and did not look any further. Thanks for pointing out. Updated my code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of issues with your code. Try something more like:

```
def reply(response)
 return 'I do too' if response == 'yes'
 return 'Dogs are better' if response == 'no'
 'Invalid response!'
end

puts 'Do you like cats?'
response = gets().chomp()
puts reply(response)
```

Pay attention to the variable names. If you keep them descriptive, it is easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: Well I like it. But it shows 'Invalid response' if I type yes or no. . .

Comment: Ah. Good call. The `chomp()` call should fix that. The `gets()` captured the newline from the user input.